# Recognizing image features regardless of their position using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, convolution

Let's assume you are using neural networks for image recognition and you have trained it to recognize a straight line.

Every time a specific column of pixels is on, and neighbouring pixels are off, a specific node fires and hence "recognizes" the line.

So far so good, but what if the line moves just a few pixels to the left or right?

The "straight line" node isn't active anymore, because the column of pixels it "reacts" to is off (the line is too far right or left).

My naive solution would be to separately train the network to recognize lines on each part of the image, but that seems messy and overkill.

Thus my questions:

**How do neural networks recognize lines regardless of where they are on the image? I read that convolutional neural networks elegantly solve this problem, can somebody explain how in not-too-technical terms?**

**And once they are recognized, how is the information about their position transported further up the chain** (since a line on the left might have a different meaning than a line on the right part of the image)**?**

Answer (score 1):

Kunihiko Fukushima proposed the hierarchical multi-layered neural network (NN) capable of robust visual pattern recognition in 1980. In his [work](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1837615), he investigated how NN trained lines. three pixel horizontal lines, vertical lines, and specific variations of diagonal lines at various angles were used as the training sample. His motivation is to see which part of his hidden layer could be counted on to fire when the desired patterns were shown up. His results also indicates that lines with all the orientation can be recognized by such a trained network.

Different from NN that only allows the input as vectors, convolution neural network (CNN) allows 2D arrays at input layer. From this aspect, it is straightforward to view CNN as a local filter in which the weights can be updated in learning process. Each node in a small part of hidden layer connect to the pixel and its neighborhood in a local region of the input image. In the line recognition training, not only do the weights within this part update, the line feature is also enhanced by learning. Yes you may already notice this acts like an edge detector, since the weights on the line pixels will increase while those on the surrounding will decrease or even turn to negative value.

An important and distinct feature of CNN is called [shared weights](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#shared-weights). It yields the line detection independent of its position and orientation (note: the weights are the same for the pixels in the local region, but different in regards to the relative positions between each neighborhood pixel to the one in the center, or the line pixel).

Besides, [MaxPooling](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#maxpooling) is also a mechanism that provides a form of translation invariance, which furtherly achieves the position independence in the line recognition.